# "NullPointerException" while sorting a double linked List

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception

I'm studying the concepts of pointers. The following list has hypothetical pointers, one pointing to the previous number, and another one, to the next number. And, there's also an element pointing to the current number. When I run the code, the console returns "NullPointerException". The logic behind the code seems okay to me. I'm a beginner and I'd really appreciate some help. I tried to comment the code as much as I could so it can be clearer to understand. Thank you.

```
aux = start; //aux points to the start of the list. both of them are of the type 'List'
            int prev = start.num; //prev points to the number on the start position. both of them are of the type 'int'
            while (aux.next != null) { //aux.next means the pointer to the next element in the list
                if (aux.num >= aux.next.num) { //if the current number is greater than the next number, or equal
                    prev = aux.next.num; //prev recieves the lower number
                    aux.next.num = aux.num; //the greater number is put after the lower number
                    aux.num = prev; //the lower number is put before the greater number
                }
                aux = aux.next; //the current element takes a step to the next element so I can progress through the list
                aux.num = aux.next.num;
        }
```

Edit: I forgot to say that this list has to be ordered ascending. It also has to be ordered descending on another method.

Comment: On which line is the NullPointerException thrown?

Comment: You code is not correct ... please read about one sorting algorithm ... start with bubble sort which is easy then try to implement it with an array... then try to do it with linked list ... We could give you the code but that will not help you learn ...

Comment: @Petter At "aux.num = aux.next.num;", line 10 of the block of code on my question.

Comment: before using any reference better check **!= null** & tell exactly on which line npe ? before that line, you can check if(aux != null && aux.next != null)

Answer (score 2):

It happens in the last two lines of your while loop.

```
aux = aux.next; //the current element takes a step to the next element so I can progress through the list
aux.num = aux.next.num;
```

Here you assign `aux = aux.next`, after that you do `aux.num = aux.next.num;`.
If `aux` is now the last element of your list, `aux.next` is `null` and `aux.next.num` will throw an NPE.

To prevent this, you could do another check before accessing `num`:

```
aux = aux.next;
if(aux.next != null) {
    aux.num = aux.next.num;
}
else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but now it goes on an infinite loop. I added the numbers "10" and "4", and printed out how it sorted. Here it is:
'prev = 10 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 4;
prev = 4 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 4;
prev = 4 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 10;
prev = 4 - aux.num = 4 - aux.next.num = 10;
prev = 4 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 10;
prev = 10 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 10;
prev = 10 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 10;
prev = 10 - aux.num = 10 - aux.next.num = 10;'

Comment: You could add an `else` block with a single `break;` which exits you loop. Since `aux.next` is `null` when you reach the `else` block, it also means you're at the end of you list and you can safely break out of the loop.

Comment: Still on infinite loop. Check out the code I added after closing my "if" statement (line 9 of the question's block of code).

'if(aux.next != null) { aux.num = aux.next.num; } else { break;}'

Comment: Are you still doing `aux = aux.next` before the if-check? I edited my answer.

Comment: I didn't check that. Now it works, but there's a problem with the "prev" variable. I added the following numbers: 4, 10, 6. When I ordered the list using this sorting method, it returned: 4, 10, 10. I presume it lost the "prev" value.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `aux.next` is not null, but You don't check this condition for `aux.prox` (I believe, `prox` is a pointer).

**edit:**

So... look at

```
aux = aux.next;
aux.num = aux.next.num;
```

You have to check if new `aux.next` is not NULL

Comment: I'm sorry, "prox" does not exist, it was my mistake to type it. The "prox" you're talking about is "next". I fixed it on the code.

Comment: Yes and I checked it and it gets on an infinite loop.